# Sorting set elements while respecting numbers?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, set

I know that the C++ `std::set` keeps its elements sorted. How can I make it keep those elements sorted while respecting numeric values?

The problem im facing is that if I try to add the elements `K1`, `K2`, and `K10`, for example, after the set sorts them as strings they get the following order:

```
K1
K10
K2
```

However, I'd like them to be in this order:

```
K1
K2
K10
```

How can I do this?

Comment: *Lexicographical order* would yield `K1 K10 K2`, so you do get the correct behaviour. If you wish to ignore `K` and compare just the numbers following it instead, you should make the explanation a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The set is indeed in this case storing the strings in lexicographical order - it just happens to be the case that this isn't' the order you'd like. Instead, you want the ordering to treat numbers numerically when comparing things.

There are a couple of ways you could do this. Here's one approach, which works by treating each number present in a string as a single entity for the purposes of comparisons.

```
struct NumericCompare {
    bool operator()(const std::string& left, const std::string& right) {
        std::istringstream lhs(left), rhs(right);

        while (lhs.peek() != EOF && rhs.peek() != EOF) {
            /* Do we see digits in either of these? */
            if (std::isdigit(lhs.peek() || std::isdigit(rhs.peek()) {
                 /* If one is a digit and the other isn't, compare the
                  * characters as usual.
                  */
                 if (!std::isdigit(lhs.peek()) || !std::isdigit(rhs.peek())) {
                     return lhs.peek() < rhs.peek();
                 }

                 /* Otherwise, we have two numbers. Read them both and compare
                  * them. Note: This assumes numbers are nonnegative and 64-bit,
                  * which may not be true in your case.
                  */
                 std::uint64_t leftN, rightN;
                 lhs >> leftN;
                 rhs >> rightN;

                 if (lhs != rhs) return lhs < rhs;
            }
            /* Neither are numbers. Compare as usual. */
            auto leftC  = lhs.get();
            auto rightC = rhs.get();
            if (leftC != rightC) return leftC < rightC;
        }

        /* At least one stream is empty. See if they both are. */
        if (lhs.peek() == EOF && rhs.peek() == EOF) return false;

        /* So exactly one of them is. lhs comes before rhs if it's empty. */
        return lhs.peek() == EOF;
    }
};
```

From here, you can make something like a

```
std::set<std::string, NumericCompare> mySet;
```

to make the comparisons go this way.